# How to create a Javascript clock with custom input time?

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a Javascript clock that can start at a custom time in the format of HH:MM:SS. The code below works fine, the clock ticks up and everything, but starts at the local time, not a custom one. I thought that passing in custom parameters to Date() would work but when I try something like

```
time = new Date(2011, 0, 1, 12, 33, 24, 567);
```

It displays just 12:33:24 and doesn't tick up or anything. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function clock() {
          var mytime = new Date();
          var seconds = mytime.getSeconds();
          var minutes = mytime.getMinutes();
          var hours = mytime.getHours();
          var currentTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
          document.getElementById("Timer").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTime;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id = "Timer">00:00:00</span>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      setInterval('clock()', 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes from `'clock()'`.

Comment: @RahulDesai: ...and the parenthesis.

Comment: `document.getElementById("Timer").firstChild.nodeValue` should be `document.getElementById("Timer").innerHTML`.

Comment: I see no one actually understands the question and all the answers think it is related to the timeout... The OP wonders why they set a start time it does not count....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider what you're doing here (syntax changed for simplicity):

```
setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

Every second you are running the `clock` function.  So when you have this:

```
var mytime = new Date();
```

Every second you will get the *current* date and time.  So it changes every second.  But when you have this:

```
var mytime = new Date(2011, 0, 1, 12, 33, 24, 567);
```

Every second you get a *constant* date and time.  So it never changes.  Thus, it always displays that same constant date and time.

Basically, you should be storing a single `Date` object and just adding a second to it every second.  (Or, more accurately, calculate the difference between the current date, which naturally already had a second added, and the custom date.  And update the value based on that difference.)  Something more like this (untested, shown for structural changes only):

```
// store when the clock began ticking
var startDate = new Date();

function clock() {

    // create the custom date, and add to it the difference
    // between when the clock started ticking and right now
    var diff = new Date().getTime() - startDate.getTime();
    var mytime = new Date(2011, 0, 1, 12, 33, 24, 567);
    mytime.setMilliseconds(mytime.getMilliseconds() + diff);

    var seconds = mytime.getSeconds();
    var minutes = mytime.getMinutes();
    var hours = mytime.getHours();

    var currentTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    document.getElementById("Timer").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTime;

}
```

Comment: You have the correct problem, but the solution is not the best. Interval is not accurate so the time will drift.

Comment: @epascarello: It's not, I know.  At best I suspect this is an academic exercise for the OP.  This is a bit of a "quick fix" to demonstrate the problem with minimal changes to the current code.

Comment: It's better to calculate the relative time difference instead of adding 1 to avoid drift... https://jsfiddle.net/nypmrdLt/

Comment: @AnthonyChu: I was just now looking into how to do that :)  Mind if I use your code in the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the example you have ticks up is you are reading a new time on every iteration. When you hard code a time, the time will always be the same. If you want the time to increase, you will need to manually track how much time has elapsed and add that to the time you want to start at.

```js
//get the start time the page loads
var startTime = new Date();
function clock() {

    //the time you want to start from
    var mytime = new Date(2011, 0, 1, 12, 33, 24, 567);
  
    ///calcualte the difference between the start and current time
    var diff = new Date() - startTime;
  
    //add that difference to the offset time
    mytime.setMilliseconds(mytime.getMilliseconds() + diff);

    //Generate your output
    var seconds = mytime.getSeconds();
    var minutes = mytime.getMinutes();
    var hours = mytime.getHours();

    var currentTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    document.getElementById("Timer").innerHTML = currentTime;

}

setInterval(clock, 1000);
clock();
```

```html
<span id="Timer">x<span>
```

Answer (score -2):

You're close - you want to pass the function by object reference to the setInterval method. When it's in quotes, and has the parentheses like you've got it, it's just treated as a string.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/687ts2zz/

```
var clock = function() {
  var mytime = new Date(),
      seconds = mytime.getSeconds(),
      minutes = mytime.getMinutes(),
      hours = mytime.getHours(),
      currentTime = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  document.getElementById("Timer").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTime;
}
setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

Comment: [WindowTimers.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)  `window.setInterval(code, delay);[...]code, in the alternate syntax, is the string of code you want to be executed repeatedly.  (This syntax is not recommended for the same reasons that using eval() should be avoided.)[...]`

Comment: I don't get it, I'm not passing it a string of code, it's an object being passed, hence the lack of quotes.

Comment: The code snippet that is shown by the OP in the question produces the same result as the one shown in your fiddle. ([fiddle using `setInterval('clock()', 1000)`](https://jsfiddle.net/687ts2zz/4/). The Problem that it might not work in jsfiddle using `setInterval('clock()', 1000)` is, because jsfiddle by default wraps the whole code into a callback function that is executed on load, and because of that `clock` is not defined in the global scope. `[...]When it's in quotes [...] it's just treated as a string.[...]` is not correct, it is treated as code that is evaluated in the global scope.