# How to sync the clock to custom time in Angular 2 and above

Tags: angular

The following code displays an analog and a digital clock with which reads the time from Date(). A HTML input time field is used to capture the time from the user. Once, the user selects the custom time and click the sync button then the clocks should be synced to custom time and keep ticking. I have tried few things with setInterval() in the Sync() but didn't get the desired result and couldn't think of other way to achieve it. Please provide on some ideas to do this.
[Link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-analog-clock-ngstyle-2hv9yp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
   import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <button (click)="Sync()" id=sync>Sync</button>
    
    <div class="clock">
      <div class="analog-clock">
        <div class="hour hand" [ngStyle]="hourHandStyle"></div>
        <div class="minute hand" [ngStyle]="minuteHandStyle"></div>
        <div class="second hand" [ngStyle]="secondHandStyle"></div>
        <div class="center-circle"></div>
        <input type="time" id="appt" name="appt" step=1 value="">
      </div>
      <div class="digital-clock">{{format(hour)}}:{{format(minute)}}:{{format(second)}}</div>
      <span>{{inputValue}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>{{inputValue}}</div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro');

    .analog-clock {
      position: relative;
      margin: 100px auto 0;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: aliceblue;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .hand {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      width: 1px;
      height: 100px;
      transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    }

    .hour {
      background-color: #f44336;
    }

    .minute {
      background-color: #3f51b5;
    }

    .second {
      background-color: #9e9e9e;
    }

    .center-circle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
      width: 12px;
      height: 12px;
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .digital-clock {
      position: absolute;
      top: 350px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
      font-size: 2em;
      font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  hourHandStyle; 
  minuteHandStyle; 
  secondHandStyle; 

  isRunning = true;
  timerId: any;

  date: Date;
  hour: number = 0;
  minute: number = 0;
  second: number = 0;

  hh1: any; mm1: any; ss1: any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.timerId = this.getTime();
  }

  animateAnalogClock() {
    this.hourHandStyle = { transform: `translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) rotate(${(this.hour * 30) + (this.minute * 0.5) + (this.second * (0.5 / 60))}deg)` };
    
    this.minuteHandStyle = { transform: `translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) rotate(${(this.minute * 6) + (this.second * 0.1)}deg)` };
    
    this.secondHandStyle = { transform: `translate3d(-50%, 0, 0) rotate(${this.second * 6}deg)` };
  }

  getTime() {
    return setInterval(() => {
      this.date = new Date();
      this.hour = this.date.getHours();
      this.minute = this.date.getMinutes();
      this.second = this.date.getSeconds();

      this.animateAnalogClock();
    }, 1000);
  }

  format(num: number) {
    return (num + '').length === 1 ? '0' + num : num + '';
  }

  setTime()
  {
    let inputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("appt")).value;
   console.log(inputValue);
   this.hh1= inputValue.substr(0,2);
   this.mm1 = inputValue.substr(3,2);
   this.ss1 = inputValue.substr(6,2);
   this.hour = + this.hh1;
   this.minute= + this.mm1;
   this.second= + this.ss1;
  }

  Sync() {

     this.setTime();
      this.animateAnalogClock();
      
  }
}
```

Comment: With the code I have written, there are two issues

1. As the current time is being called every second to get the latest time, the custom time is getting refreshed after displaying just once
2. The custom time is not ticking, it always displays the time which is provided as input.

Any suggestions would be of a great help


Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the solution from the following link and it worked for me.

[How to create a Javascript clock with custom input time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35322669/how-to-create-a-javascript-clock-with-custom-input-time)